# PHP xmlparser with $_GET parameter

Tags: php, get, parameter-passing, xml-parsing

I use a xml_parser to parse an xml. When I have a string like

```
$simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
```

it works. But the problem is when I use a $_GET parameter.

```
$simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
$parser = xml_parser_create();
$valid = xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $simple, $response, $index);
xml_parser_free($parser);
echo $valid;
```

When run xml.php, it returns 1. It works

```
$simple= $_GET['simple'];
$parser = xml_parser_create();
$valid = xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $simple, $response, $index);
xml_parser_free($parser);
echo $valid;
```

When run

```
xml.php?simple=<para><note>simple note</note></para>
```

It returns 0. It doesn´t work.

But the $_GET parameter is OK:

```
echo $_GET['simple]
```

prints

```
<para><note>simple note</note></para>
```

By the way, I have magic quotes off.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what you see on the screen/browser is `<para><note>simple note</note></para>` It probably means the `<` and `>` are **not** really tag delimiters.  (but `&gt;` and `&lt;`)
Do view source on the page when you do the echo, and the truth will come out.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the key. I used html_entity_decode($simple) and it worked! How quickly this question was answered!! And I have been more than 1 hour searching and trying... Thanks again to Mark and you, Itay

Comment: @Alberto = if this answer described the problem correctly, you can always accept it...